# Encoding issues with Microsoft Word characters in an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, encoding, ms-word

I'm writing a function to convert MS Word-styled text into Adobe InDesign-formatted text (it uses a kind of XML to indicate styling). The text is pasted into a TinyMCE rich text editor, which then sends the HTML-formatted code to a php function.

I've tried this function to clean up the code once it reaches my conversion code:

```
$text = iconv("windows-1250", "UTF-8", $html);
```

When I use any 'special' kind of characters, things go wrong. £ signs, é (or any other accents), and a variety of 'curly' apostrophes/quote marks seem to break things. For example, if I try to convert a `£` sign, the code returns `\u0141`, but I get the `Ł` symbol displayed onscreen when the function returns.

Does anybody know what I can do to prevent Word's weird characters breaking everything I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this. I was using `escape()` to pass the values, but replaced this with `encodeURIComponent()` instead (and removed the `iconv()` call in my php code), which seems to have fixed it.